# setTimeout(): If not defined in EcmaScript spec, where can I learn how it works?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I had [another question in SO about setTimeout()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8821765/settimeout-on-recursive-function-within-a-self-invoking-function), where a user mentioned that ***if the function argument is a string it gets evaluated in global scope, other wise it's not***. This was an eye-opener, so I tried to find more info about how setTimeout actually works, but it's not part of the EcmaScript spec and not even MDN had that specific of of information I found in SO.

Is there some good reference about how `setTimeout()` works?

Comment: [Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) is the MDN page.

Comment: In the HTML5 draft: http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#timers

Comment: the MDN does have some useful info about it: "Code executed by setTimeout() is run in a separate execution context to the function from which it was called."

Comment: @MattK: Yes, but the rest of that paragraph talks about `this`, which is different from scope.

Comment: So if setTimeout and other similar API is not defined in ECMAscript, javascript itself should be synchronous language, right? can we say that?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`setTimeout` and such aren't in the ECMAScript specification because they're not JavaScript features. They're features of the browser environment's `window` object. Other environments (Windows Scripting Host, NodeJS, etc.) won't necessarily have those features.

The W3C has been trying to standardize the `window` object and its various features (including `setTimeout`), [the latest is in the timers section of the HTML5 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#timers). A lot of it is codifying what browsers already do, although some of it (like saying that the minimum interval value must be `4` [milliseconds]) seems (to me) to be out-of-place for an API specification and implementations seem to make up their own minds ([in tests](http://jsbin.com/aREWitER/1), you can see current browsers happily doing a shorter interval, with the apparent exception of Opera which appears to do what the spec says).

Comment: Wow those HTML5 specs always make me seasick. But I hadn't thought about the situation with respect to web workers.

Comment: I think that W3C Window Object spec is abandoned. HTML5 completely specifies the `window` object, or at least attempts to.

Answer (score 5):

The `setTimeout()` method is a method on the `window` object.  You can find the link to the MDN documentation below:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout

Comment: I just updated that with a mention of the scope used to evaluate string parameters.