# setTimeout function and asynchronous function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, scheduled-tasks, settimeout

This is with regard to how `setTimeout` executes its callbacks.

I have have the following

```
function f1 (argument) {
    console.log('f1 start');
    for(var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i)
        for(var j = 0; j < 10000; ++j);
    console.log('f1 complete');
}

function f2 (argument) {
    console.log('f2 start');
    for(var i = 0; i < 1000; ++i)
        for(var j = 0; j < 10000; ++j);
    console.log('f2 complete');
}

function f3 (argument) {
    console.log('f3 start');
    for(var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        for(var j = 0; j < 10000; ++j);
    console.log('f3 complete');
}

setTimeout(f1,0);
setTimeout(f2,0);
setTimeout(f3,0);
console.log('In main2');
```

**Output:**

> In main2
>
> f1 start
>
> f1 complete
>
> f3 start
>
> f3 complete
>
> f2 start
>
> f2 complete

John Resig explains in his [article](http://ejohn.org/blog/how-javascript-timers-work/), `setTimeout` queues all the callbacks until the current block of code completes its execution. This StackOverflow [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/779379/why-is-settimeoutfn-0-sometimes-useful) explains even though it appears as if the events are fired immediately, they are actually queued.

In the above code you'd notice, `f1()` is the longest, followed by f`3()` and then `f2()`.

My question is, why the observed order(`f1` first, then `f3` and finally `f2`)? If the events are queued, it should simply be in the same order as they were called (`f1`,`f2`,`f3`). How and why does the JavaScript engine pick the longest job first?

[EDIT]
Note: The above code was run in Node.js

Comment: check this out : https://github.com/caolan/async

Comment: I got the sequenced output in node as well `f1  f2 then f3`

Comment: I don't see how it is possible for you to get that output. The functions must always be called in order (i.e. `f1`, then `f2`, then `f3`). There's no way for JavaScript to figure out the longest function without profiling it. Asynchronous functions are always queued.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regardless of the "javascript engine" question (there is no such thing, there is a [language specification](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) and different implementations) because it depends (see this [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852198/settimeout-if-not-defined-in-ecmascript-spec-where-can-i-learn-how-it-works)), you may want to use promises if you want to ensure a specific sequence order.

Check the Q library at https://github.com/kriskowal/q

Or this RSVP library https://github.com/tildeio/rsvp.js

The Promises/a+ spec is [here](http://wiki.commonjs.org/wiki/Promises/A)

Is available for node and for the browser

My own test on node v0.10.21 (same as firefox and chromium's console):

```
~/workspace/tmp$ node test.js 
In main2
f1 start
f1 complete
f2 start
f2 complete
f3 start
f3 complete
```

Comment: Thanks for that SO question - makes me wonder about the source of John Resig's article. And FYI, there's a wiki page on [Javascript Engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaScript_engine). So, it wouldn't entirely be wrong to say that there is such a thing would it? :)

Comment: There is a section "Implementations" in that wiki article that says what I say, but yes, it's not entirely wrong to say it :)

Answer (score 1):

I have tried your code in firebug console and I got the output in following order, which I think as expected.

In main2
f1 start
f1 complete
f2 start
f2 complete
f3 start
f3 complete

I am using firefox 12.0 with fedora.