# in javascript, timer is not a part of Ecma Standard?

Tags: javascript, ecma262

is timer not a part of Ecma Standard? for example

```
setTimeout, setInterval
```

Comment: setTimeout, setInterval should be the browser web api.

Comment: Please, you're encouraged to first google or search for the answers before asking the question here.
This question was already answered in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8852198/settimeout-if-not-defined-in-ecmascript-spec-where-can-i-learn-how-it-works

Answer (score 0):

That's correct. It does not exist in [the official specification](https://tc39.es/ecma262/). One could construct a valid ECMAScript interpreter that does not know of `setTimeout` or `setInterval`.

However, it does exist [in the HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-settimeout).

Comment: usually mix up the Ecma spec and Html spec