# recursive function vs setInterval vs setTimeout javascript

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion, settimeout, setinterval

i am using NodeJs and need call a infinite function, but i dont know what is the best for a optimal performance.

**recursive function**

```
function test(){
//my code
test();
}
```

**setInterval**

```
setInterval(function(){
//my code
},60);
```

**setTimeout**

```
function test(){
//my code
setTimeout(test,60);
}
```

I want the best performance without collapse the server. My code have several arithmetic operations.

appreciate any suggestions to optimize the javascript performance.

Comment: depends on the function you are calling

Answer (score 39):

Be carefull.. your first code would block JavaScript event loop.

Basically in JS is something like list of functions which should be processed. When you call `setTimeout`, `setInterval` or `process.nextTick` you will add given function to this list and when the right times comes, it will be processed..

Your code in the first case would never stop so it would never let another functions in the event list to be processed.

Second and third case is good.. with one little difference.

If your function takes to process for example 10ms and interval will be yours 60ms..

- function with setInterval will be processed in times: 0-10, 60-70, 120-130, ... (so it has only 50ms delay between calls)
- But with setTimeout it will be:

  - if you call func first: 0-10, 70-80, 140-150, 210-220, ...
  - if you call setTimeout first: 60-70, 130-140, 200-210, ...

So the difference is delay between starts of your function which can be important in some interval based systems, like games, auctions, stock market.. etc..

Good luck with your recursion :-)

Comment: This is the most complete and correct answer and should be accepted as an answer imo. Thanks!

Comment: I see, you are talking about cca 10ms to perform execution within function. But also notable diffference is: the first example (setInterval) will be executed not immidiately, but after 60 ms. The second example (setTimeout) will be executed immidiately and then each 60 ms, upon invoking function test().

Answer (score 13):

As already mentioned, endless recursive functions lead to a stack overflow. Time triggered callbacks will be executed in an own context with a clear stack.

`setInterval` is useful for more accurate periodic calls over recursive `setTimeout`, however, there is a drawback: *The callback will be triggered even if an uncaught exception was thrown*. This usually produces a several bytes long log entry every 60 milliseconds, 1'440'000 entries per day. Furthermore a `setInterval` callback with heavy load could end up in an unresponsive script or even hole system.

Recursive `setTimeout` immediate before return from function will *not* be executed if any exception hasn't been caught. It will guarantee a time frame for other tasks after return from the callback function independent of the function's execution time.

Answer (score 7):

Not sure what you're trying to accomplish, but here's a "safe" way to use recursion... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24208676/how-to-use-recursion-in-javascript/24208677

```
/*
this will obviously crash... and all recursion is at risk of running out of call stack and breaking your page...

function recursion(c){
    c = c || 0;
    console.log(c++);
    recursion(c);
}
recursion();

*/

// add a setTimeout to reset the call stack and it will run "forever" without breaking your page!
// use chrome's heap snapshot tool to prove it to yourself.  :)

function recursion(c){
    setTimeout(function(c){
        c = c || 0;
        console.log(c++);
        recursion(c);
    },0,c);
}

recursion();

// another approach is to use event handlers, but that ultimately uses more code and more resources
```

Answer (score 7):

Recursive `setTimeout` guarantees a delay between the executions, `setInterval` – does not.

Let’s compare two code fragments. The first one uses `setInterval`:

```
let i = 1;
setInterval(function() {
  func(i);
}, 100);
```

The second one uses recursive `setTimeout`:

```
let i = 1;
setTimeout(function run() {
  func(i);
  setTimeout(run, 100);
}, 100);
```

For `setInterval` the internal scheduler will run `func(i)` every 100ms.

The real delay between `func` calls for `setInterval` is less than in the code!

That’s normal, because the time taken by `func's` execution “consumes” a part of the interval.

It is possible that `func's` execution turns out to be longer than we expected and takes more than 100ms.

In this case the engine waits for `func` to complete, then checks the scheduler and if the time is up, runs it again immediately.

In the edge case, if the function always executes longer than `delay` ms, then the calls will happen without a pause at all.

The recursive `setTimeout` guarantees the fixed `delay` (here 100ms).

Answer (score 4):

Assuming the "perfomance delay" described by [Jan Juna](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26370124/3309466), I have tried this simple script to check if there are any differences in terms of throughput:

**Interval:**

```
const max = 50;
const timer = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 400, 500];

function crono(timer) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const exit = [];
    let i = 0
    setInterval(() => i++, timer);

    setInterval(() => {
      exit.push(i);
      i = 0;
      if (exit.length === max) {
        const sum = exit.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0);
        const avg = sum / exit.length;
        console.log(`${timer} = ${avg}`);
        resolve(avg)
      }
    }, 1000);
  });
}

Promise.all(timer.map(crono)).then(process.exit);
```

**Timeout:**

```
const max = 50;
const timer = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 400, 500];

function crono(timer) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const exit = [];
    let i = 0

    const redo = () => {
      i++
      setTimeout(redo, timer);
    }

    setInterval(() => {
      exit.push(i);
      i = 0;
      if (exit.length === max) {
        const sum = exit.reduce((a, b) => (a + b), 0);
        const avg = sum / exit.length;
        console.log(`${timer} = ${avg}`);
        resolve(x)
      }
    }, 1000);

    redo();
  });
}

Promise.all(timer.map(crono)).then(process.exit);
```

And this is the output vith nodejs 8.11: that shows no difference in terms of throughput:

[image: results]

Answer (score 0):

The recursive function cause a stack overflow. That's not what you want.

The `setInterval` and `setTimeout` ways you have shown are identical, except that `setInterval` is more clear.

I'd recommend `setInterval`. (After all, that is what it's for.)

Comment: you are right with the recursive function, it is descarted. But what about setinterval over call?

Comment: @Vorge, what is "descarted" and what is "call"?

Comment: sorry, "discarded" "recursive function". after doing some tests, I have come to the conclusion that the best is the setTimeout. this way we prevent any overcall.

Answer (score 0):

`recursive function` : Endless recursive functions lead to a stack overflow.

`setTimeout` code will always have at least a 60ms delay after the previous callback execution (it may end up being more, but never less)

`setInterval` will attempt to execute a callback every 60ms regardless of when the last callback was executed.

Answer (score -7):

//use setInterval function

```
setInterval(function(){Property=value;},1000);
```

1000ms=1second;
property like style.width etc;

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! This question is about Node.js, a server-side technology (not in the browser). If you believe that `setInterval()` is the "best for ... optimal performance" (as the question asks), try to explain *why* it performs better than the other options. Enjoy your time on the site!