# why is this code not able to change the opacity of an element by its id

Tags: javascript, html, css, opacity

I am wondering why the opacity for the element is not temporary reduced when the appropriate button is pressed. Thanks for your help.

```js
function sleep(miliseconds) {
  var currentTime = new Date().getTime();

  while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {}
}

function temporarHide(ev) {
  document.getElementById(ev).style.opacity = '0.16';
  sleep(1500);
  document.getElementById(ev).style.opacity = '1';
}
```

```html
<div id="epicenter">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/45/000" alt="Schwarz" id="black">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/45/00f" alt="Blau" id="blue">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/45/0f0" alt="Grün" id="green">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/45/ddd" alt="Grau" id="grey">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/45/a0d" alt="Lila" id="lila">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/45/e73" alt="Orange" id="orange">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/45/f00" alt="Rot" id="red">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/45/ff0" alt="Gelb" id="yellow">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/45/fcc" alt="Rosa" id="rosa">
</div>
<button onclick="temporarHide('black')">black</button>
<button onclick="temporarHide('blue')">blue</button>
<button onclick="temporarHide('green')">green</button>
<button onclick="temporarHide('grey')">grey</button>
<button onclick="temporarHide('lila')">lila</button>
<button onclick="temporarHide('orange')">orange</button>
<button onclick="temporarHide('red')">red</button>
<button onclick="temporarHide('yellow')">yellow</button>
<button onclick="temporarHide('rosa')">rosa</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using a single event listener, rather than individual ones - easier to maintain and less code. I also suggest using classes rather than style tags. Again, easier to maintain, but also makes things like `css transitions` easier. Here, the items fade in and fade out.

Finally, I opted for `setTimeout` rather than your sleep function. `setTimeout` is the right tool for this job. As [this S.O. post discusses](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26370124/1772933), `while()` (and other) loops block code execution and continuously run until complete. This is bad for performance in general. It probably won't crash the browser with this particular use-case, but it's good to stick with best practices. `setTimeout` and `setInterval` run async and trigger only when complete.

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {

  // one click-event listener to rule them all
  document.addEventListener('click', e => {

    // testing to make sure the item clicked is a button and is in the 
    // <div class='color-b'> element
    if (e.target.tagName === 'BUTTON' && e.target.closest('.color-b')) {
      let ev = e.target.innerText.trim() // get the id directly from the button text
      document.getElementById(ev).classList.add('dim');
      setTimeout(() => document.getElementById(ev).classList.remove('dim'), 1500);
    }
  })
})
```

```css
img {
  transition: opacity 1s;
  width: 58px;
}

button {
  width: 58px;
}

.dim {
  opacity: 0.16;
}
```

```html
<div id="epicenter">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/65/000" alt="Schwarz" id="black">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/65/00f" alt="Blau" id="blue">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/65/0f0" alt="Grün" id="green">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/65/ddd" alt="Grau" id="grey">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/65/a0d" alt="Lila" id="lila">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/65/e73" alt="Orange" id="orange">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/65/f00" alt="Rot" id="red">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/65/ff0" alt="Gelb" id="yellow">
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/65/fcc" alt="Rosa" id="rosa">
</div>
<div class='color-b'>
  <button>black</button>
  <button>blue</button>
  <button>green</button>
  <button>grey</button>
  <button>lila</button>
  <button>orange</button>
  <button>red</button>
  <button>yellow</button>
  <button>rosa</button>
</div>
```