# Start and stop interval on button click

Tags: javascript, jquery, intervals

I have this code here and i want the background to stop changing when i click the same button (the interval to stop). But i cannot work my way around it.(The else part works because in the console isCicked changes it's value).

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn');
let body = document.querySelector('body');
let isClicked = false;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    let x;
    let y;
    if(isClicked == false){
        isClicked = true;
         x= setInterval(function(){
            let r,g,b;
            r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
            g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
            b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
            body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
            btn.classList.toggle('button-style')
        },1000)
    }else{
        isClicked = false;
        clearInterval(x);
    }
    console.log(isClicked);

})
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: You need to declare `x` outside the listener. You redeclare it on each click and overwrite the interval id so there's nothing to clear.

Answer (score 1):

To fix your current code you need to declare `x` outside the event listener since as it stands you redeclare it on each click and overwrite your stored interval id.

```
let isClicked = false;
let x;

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
    if(isClicked == false){
        isClicked = true;
        x = setInterval(function(){
    
    ...
}
```

But you can actually simplify a little by combining `isClicked` and `x` and just checking if an interval is stored.

```js
let btn = document.getElementById('btn');
let body = document.querySelector('body');

let interval = null;

btn.addEventListener('click', function () {
  if (interval === null) {
    interval = setInterval(function () {
      let r, g, b;
      r = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      g = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      b = Math.round(Math.random() * 255);
      body.style.backgroundColor = `rgb(${r},${g},${b})`;
      btn.classList.toggle('button-style');
    }, 1000);
  } else {
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = null;
  }
  console.log(interval);
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Click</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather then trying to manage the state of `setInterval`, you could use `setTimeout` and recursion (a function calling itself) to create an interval. Likewise, rather than using variable mutation, since you're toggling a class on the button, you can just use the button itself as the exit condition for the recursion.

```js
let btn = document.querySelector('#btn'),
    body = document.querySelector('body');

function ChangeBackground() {
  if (btn.classList.contains('button-style')) { //check exit condition
    body.style.backgroundColor = '#' + Math.random().toString(16).slice(-6);        
    setTimeout(ChangeBackground, 1000); //recursion
  }
}

btn.addEventListener('click', function(){
  this.classList.toggle('button-style'); //toggle exit condition
  ChangeBackground(); //start recursion
});
```

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Click</button>
```

Comment: The recursion seems a fine solution, more discussion of tradeoffs here: [recursive function vs setInterval vs setTimeout javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23178015/recursive-function-vs-setinterval-vs-settimeout-javascript), but your color calculation sometimes returns invalid strings.

Comment: Copied the color generator from a comment on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1484506/random-color-generator. Picked it because it was a short one-liner and voted highly. Can't say I've ever actually used it though.

Comment: Who would have thought someone would post invalid code and people would just upvote it without testing it?!? I picked another one liner from the post in my previous comment and it tested 100% over 1 million iterations, so I'm going to call it valid. For future reference `(Math.random()*0xFFFFFF<<0).toString(16)` is not valid. Thanks for pointing this out.